# CSS performance with respect to inheritance

Tags: html, css, performance, dom

I am aware than ID rules are faster than class rules, which are faster than tag rules, which are faster than universal rules, as noted on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS). My question pertains to CSS performance with respect to inheritance. For example, which of the following is more efficient?

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

or

```
h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.article-text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

While there is only one `<body>` tag in the DOM, there could be hundreds of `p.article-text` elements. Since there is only one `<body>` tag, does that mean that a `<body>` style is more efficient, even though I'd be restyling the `<h1>` elements? Or is it more efficient to style the `.article-text` elements, since doing so would use a more specific selector and I wouldn't need to worry about restyling the `<h1>` elements?

Always wondered this. Thoughts?

Comment: Do a benchmark and find out?

Comment: I'd guess that the "cascading" of CSS (inheriting styles from parent elements) is highly efficient. This doesn't require a selector at all. My understanding is that `body` should be styled the way you want the main body of plain text within the document styled -- that what it's the container for.

Comment: In the grand scheme of page performance, [it's not worth worrying about](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/) (or at least not worth worrying about until you've addressed many other factors: concatenation, minification, etc.)

Comment: @Thomas W: Cascading has a very specific meaning in CSS. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html. Cascading is cascading, and inheritance is inheritance (although one could say that inheritance is part of the cascade).

Comment: I know this is about details, but even with insane CSS sheets with thousands of many dynamic bindings like `div[^="someField"] { }, ... #someField1314 {}` modern browsers (even on phones) do this blazingly fast. Also notice that once the CSS file is cached, it doesn't matter if it's hundreds of kilobytes. I build a heavy CSS animation-driven website some time ago which the CSS files together were over 3 MegaBytes big (compressed :P). I just used an AJAX loader once (a bit like Flash clips do). Once cached every page load was instant :) I would sweat more over big JavaScript chunks ;)

Comment: Extra notice; you can also show the base design of the page instantly and AJAX load the rest of the content (complex CSS that only happens on animation and/or hover/popups) in the back. It also works to put the loading scripts right before the `</body>` tag closes to win a bit of rendering time. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the MDN article you showed is written in a harmful way, as it proposes to focus on CSS micro-optimizations while almost always page speed can be increased in different ways (eg. [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) has interesting hints).

I can't remember any situation in my websites where CSS was a bottleneck. You might want to see "Timeline" in Chrome Developer Tools on some pages and notice that the amount of time spent on working with styles is usually insignificant compared to other events.

If I was to give advice, I'd rather go the other way and use CSS preprocessing tools like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to improve **maintainability**. This might even eventually help to reduce number of rules.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by steveax. It's not worth worrying about.
Moreover, the answer really depends on the browser and on the HTML actually given.

Answer (score 0):

i would say the top one is probably faster out of the two but tbh like everyone has said with the browsers we have ATM and devices and connections speeds you wouldn't notice a difference unless you have a huge site that has more than 40 - 50 pages that's when you should look into slim lining your code